# Minimizing a function scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I got a function (error like) which I have to minimize and obtain new parameters alpha and r:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as opt

def integrand(t, alpha, r):
    return np.exp(-alpha*(t-r))**2

def my_function(alpha, r):
    return quad(integrand, 0, 5.0, args=(alpha, r))[0]

alpha = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 0.1)
r = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 0.1)
x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
res = opt.minimize(my_function, x0, args=(alpha, r), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
```

My first question is if I picked up the right minimization method. If so could anybody elaborate what arguments I have to pass to the minimize method?

Currently the error message is returned:

```
File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    res = opt.minimize(my_function, x0, args=(alpha, r), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 439, in minimize
    return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1159, in _minimize_cg
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 289, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 622, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 556, in _approx_fprime_helper
    f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 289, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: my_function() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what arguments are passed, but you can use `my_function(*args, **kwargs): print(args, kwargs)` to see what you're actually getting passed to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to minimize with respect to r and alpha, then, you must pass a starting point, that is, initial values.

My Solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as opt


def integrand(t, alpha, r):
    return np.exp(-alpha*(t-r))**2


def my_function(parameters):
    alpha = parameters[0]
    r = parameters[1]
    return quad(integrand, 0, 5.0, args=(alpha, r))[0]

alpha_0 = 1
r_0 = 1

res = opt.minimize(my_function, np.asarray([alpha_0, r_0]), method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
print(res)
```

Output:

```
fun: 0.0018415003336983448
     jac: array([-0.00523077,  0.00762011])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 2
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 2.06899361, -1.1785839 ])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have one more question. I would like to change integration bounds to variables. I've tried to pass additional argument to the  my_function(parameters) function such as: x = parameters[2] and return quad(integrand, 0, x, args=(alpha, r))[0]. In this case x is also minimized. How could I circumnavigate this issue?

Comment: @eyllanesc , I just found out that my votes were reversed. Sorry: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289026/can-moderators-use-your-account-to-downvote-answers-that-youve-voted-up/289027#289027